# How do I get the clicked element's info (from the scope) in a given AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Well, let me describe my original problem that's being aroused time to time. Consider the following product.html page:

```
<div data-ng-controller="productsCtrl" data-ng-init="getProducts()" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div data-ng-repeat="section in sections">
            <h2>{{section.name}}</h2>
            <div class="products-container">
                <div data-ng-repeat="product in section.products">
                    <img alt="{{product.name}}" class="product-img" data-zoomable-image="/path_to_large_img_or_empty_if_no_image_to_zoom" data-ng-src="/path_to_thumbnail_img">
                    <div class="product">
                        <!-- Product Info -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The productsCtrl controller is obviously responsible to get the products information, one of which is the thumbnail / large image url of the product. The idea is to create a directive that controls the img element based on "data-zoomable" attribute on a given image. If the attribute's value is empty, there's no image to be displayed; Otherwise, a modal box should be opened to display the image.

So far, so good. So let me show the zoomableImage directive:

```
app.directive('zoomableImage', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var zoomIn = element.wrap('<a href="#" class="zoom-in"></a>').click(function (e) {
                var href = element.data('zoomableImage');

                var modal = $('#zoomInModal');

                //Here, I need to pass the "product's name" to the zoomInCtrl's scope.
                //This can be done using the following 3 lines of code...

                var s = modal.scope();
                s.product = 'The clicked element\'s name obtained from the DOM "element"';
                s.$apply();

                //I believe that those 3 above lines suck, since I'm not supposed to
                //set the scope of another controller in a directive. Right?

                modal.prependTo('body').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $('<span class="label label-info">Zoom In</span>').insertAfter(zoomIn);
        }
    };
});
```

So, the question is that what's the correct way of passing the "clicked" product's Name, Part#, and Image URL to the dialog I'm going to open above? Please note that the ProductsCtrl returns an array of section, each section contains multiple products and so on...

Of course, I can put the name, part# and other related information in different data attributes of the img element, but I do believe this duplicates the information that's already there in the products controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the reference of your product objects(s) to the directive by adding this to the directive:

```
scope: {
    product: '='
}
```

The object is then shared between your controller and your directive instance.
You have to add the attribute in your html too:

```
<img data-product="product" data-zoomable-image="..." ... >
```

EDIT:
Modal should be a service. Checkout the [angular-bootstrap modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: Shouldn't it be product: '=' ? product is actually an object, not a function. Do you know of any document that explains this thoroughly?

Comment: You are right. Here is the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thank you. I can now get the correct scope in the directive. However, I still need to pass this "product" to the modal. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: I would recommend to create a service that manages the modal HTML. A modal is one of the exceptions where it is ok that a service does DOM operations. Make sure you checkout the angular-bootstrap $modal service: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js. You can also use it. It is very flexible and you can modify the HTML template to your needs.